# Order of middlewares in Nuxt3 layers

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt3

In my project I have a Nuxt layer B extending a Nuxt project A.

I noticed that `/middleware` files are called in alphabetical order as should be but first all the middlewares of B and then all the middlewares of A.

If for example I have in A the following middlewares:

- `00.first.global.ts`
- `01.second.global.ts`

And in B these ones:

- `10.third.global.ts`
- `11.fourth.global.ts`

The final ordering of calls will be:

- `10.third.global.ts`
- `11.fourth.global.ts`
- `00.first.global.ts`
- `01.second.global.ts`

That it's not what I want.

Is there a way to force the rearrangement of the middlewares globally alphabetically?

Comment: For the moment the solution I found is moving all the middlewares inside plugins, using the `addRouteMiddleware` function, this because plugins are loaded in the correct order.

Comment: Did you find another solution? This is really annoying..

Comment: @oemera no... but didn't search for it neither... for the moment I'll go on like this

Comment: you can track this issue, there seems to be a fix in progress: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/25891